# Could'nt punch through NAT(or NAT not in place)

Tags: software-installation, nat

I am trying to install Ethereum for Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the mentioned [thread](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3393/building-ethereum-ubuntu-14-04-no-such-file-or-directory-error**). This is the error description I am getting! Maybe the problem is with the proxy bypassing settings. If someone could add some light over the issue...

```
**Please enter your MASTER password: 
Ethereum (++) 0.9.41
  Code by Gav Wood et al, (c) 2013, 2014, 2015.
Transaction Signer: XE10203TGOLG20FX2X46KEOAQY0J7OND56 (06c45f10-757c-4ac4-1aba-f846def126d7 - 0079eeef)
Mining Beneficiary: XE10203TGOLG20FX2X46KEOAQY0J7OND56 (06c45f10-757c-4ac4-1aba-f846def126d7 - 0079eeef)
Foundation: XE55PXQKKK4B9BYPBGT1XCYW6R5ELFAT6EM (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - de0b2956)
  ℹ  12:27:18|p2p  UPnP device: http://172.26.21.17:1990/WFADevice.xml [st: upnp:rootdevice ]

⧎ ✘  12:27:18|p2p  Couldn't punch through NAT (or no NAT in place).
```

Node ID:

```
enode://e31b85cc980158aa5cc5a6b8a8e35e97f29e1dff98592dbb30a4abceec7a90321ac8a3e6228189c00f5f13cca7e56511cfb90913f9e676bf4b8f5a6ac309f927@0.0.0.0:0
⧎ ✘  12:27:18|eth  Error resolving host address... poc-9.ethdev.com:30303 : Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later
⧎ ✘  12:27:18|eth  Error resolving host address... gav.ethdev.com:30300 : Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later
```

This is the result for **apt-cache search ethereum**

```
 root@deadman-Inspiron-3558:/home/deadman# apt-cache search ethereum
console - Ethereum console.
ethereum - Meta-package to install geth (CLI) and other tools
libethereum - Support libraries for cpp-ethereum.
libethereum-dev - Development files for cpp-ethereum (CLI and GUI)
ethereum-gui - Ethereum Go client GUI
cpp-ethereum - The full stack of cpp-ethereum binaries and libraries.
cpp-ethereum-gui - Reference GUI (AlethZero)
libethereum-gui - Support libraries for the AlethZero, AlethOne GUIs and Mix IDE.
ethereum-cli - Ethereum CLI client.
mist - Mist browser, official Ethereum GUI client.
eth - Command line client (eth).
neth - NEthereum ncurses client.
rlp - Ethereum RLP.
testeth - Ethereum testing (testeth).
geth - Ethereum CLI client.
ethminer - Ethereum Miner.
ethkey - Ethereum Key Utility.
ethvm - Ethereum VM Utility.
bootnode - Ethereum bootnode.
evm - Ethereum evm tool.
disasm - Ethereum disasm tool.
rlpdump - Ethereum rlpdump tool.
ethtest - Ethereum ethtest tool.
alethone - AlethOne basic Ethereum GUI
flu - Experimental Ethereum client with Proof of Authority consensus.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ethereum (++) 0.9.41

This is a very old version. Where did you get this from? It was released 14 months ago in Summer 2015 and it seems the seednodes are dead by now.

I recommend to upgrade to version [1.2.9](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.9) or check out the latest [develop](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum).

And regarding to the NAT issue: Try enabling UPnP on your router.

Comment: If you could just guide me as in how to upgrade my cpp-ethereum to version 1.2.9.   i tried using sudo apt-get upgrade cpp-ethereum but to no avail.

Comment: how did you install it in first place? what's the result of `apt-cache search ethereum`?

Comment: I followed the above chain for installation procedure[https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3393/building-ethereum-ubuntu-14-04-no-such-file-or-directory-error]

Comment: use this: http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html